# how to prove linear independence for time shifted functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions

If we have two linearly independent functions $ f_1(x), f_2(x) $, I need to prove the linear independence of these functions $\{f_1(x)f_1(x+t), f_2(x)f_2(x+t), f_1(x)f_2(x+t)\}$, where $t$ is a shift operator.

Do you have any idea where to start? and what kind of assumption i should put on the basic functions in order to hold the independence of the functions family.

**Note**: What is needed just a start point in this direction. Any hints would be appreciated.